# How to hide sidenav when click anywhere on the body except sidenav?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    }

    .sidenav {
        height: 100%;
        width: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #111;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.5s;
        padding-top: 60px;
    }

    .sidenav a {
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #818181;
        display: block;
        transition: 0.3s
    }

    .sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus{
        color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .sidenav .closebtn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 25px;
        font-size: 36px;
        margin-left: 50px;
    }

    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
      .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
      .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
    }
    </style>
    <body>

    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>

    <h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
    <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>

    <script>
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    }

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Above is my code, I want to hide sidenav on clicking anywhere on the body, like it is happening on clicking the cross icon on the sidenav. If there is any other idea would also be appreciated.
Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
 $(document).click(function(e) {
                          if ( $(e.target).closest('#mySidenav').length === 0 ) {
                            $('#mySidenav').css('display','none');
                             }
                            });
```

Comment: Thanks Nihar but this is not working, tried it but does not get anything